# React - how to display data value in select menu

Tags: reactjs, dataset

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j5p1ra?file=index.tsx)

Its a simple react app where I'm creating a select menu from data in an array

The select menu has a `value` attribute and a `data-number` attribute.

When the select menu changes I want to display the value and data-number.

I can't display the data-number using dataset

```
setNumber(e.currentTarget.dataset.number);
```

How can I output the data-number value

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the `number` from the `datas` array depending on the value you collected by `e.target.value`.

```
const handleChange = e => {
   console.log('value = ', e.target.value);
   console.log(datas.find( data => data.value === e.target.value).number);
   setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
   setNumber(datas.find( data => data.value === e.target.value).number);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat might seem long but you can access `<option>` element using -
**e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset.number.**
This will return the value of your data attribute.

Where e.target.selectedIndex is the index of the selected option.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can change as follow.

```
const handleChange = e => {
    ...
    console.log('number = ', e.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.number);
    setNumber(e.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.number);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
  const onChange =(e) => {
  const selectElement = e.currentTarget;
  const selectedOption = selectElement.childNodes[selectElement.selectedIndex]
  const selectedNumber =  selectedOption.getAttribute('data-number');
  setNumber(selectedNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-number"))` to get the `data-number` attribute value of selected option.

I also tried in you demo code , it is working fine

```
const handleChange = e => {
        console.log('value = ', e.target.value);
        console.log('number = ', e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-number"));  
        setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
        setNumber(e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-number"));
      };
```